# What effect does surface have on light absorption at different wavelengths?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, absorption, x-rays, infrared-radiation

I am a bit confused and need a well rounded explanation.
Have a look at two scenarios:

- A metal plate with small scratches on it appears diffuse in the optical spectrum, because the roughness reflects the light in different directions. In the infrared you don't see these scratches, because they are much smaller than the wavelength and thus the scratches have very little effect on the reflection direction. Or emissivity if you will.
- If you have seen nanoporous gold or gold nanoparticles in solution they appear black. The particles are much smaller than the wavelength (<50nm). If you roughen up a surface, the emissivity/absorptivity increases, because the light gets reflected multiple times reducing the amount of light coming back.

So I have two real phenomenons, but their explanations don't fit together.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think that if you conside that objects as small as molecule or ions can have colour you are probably able to solve your dilemma. Don't equate optics from surfaces to absorption phenomena in a sample. Sometimes even a rough out of scale sketch helps. Even if you keep to treat the nanoparticles as nanomirrors, what will happen to a ray entering a multitude of them?

Comment: @Alchimista I, for one, don't know what you are getting at here.

Comment: @garyp OP is just treating reflection and absorption on the same basis. The fact that a particle is smaller than the wavelength it dies not mean anything on its "inner" electronic transition. Else no dye would exist. Nanoparticles happen to be in the middle depending on their size. The two supposedly conflicting explanation do not need to fit because the underlying transitions are of different nature. One thing is spectroscopy of a metal bar, one thing is spectroscopy on the same metal ion in solution,to see what we are speaking about. Nanoparticles can have their own absorption spectrum!

Comment: Or see it like this. IR does not see scratches. But IR can go as small as a bond vibration. It is the underlying mechanism that matters rather than length.

Comment: @Alchimista I don't mean to be rude, but you are writing in riddles. You should post an answer where you explain what mechanisms do play a role if it's not the size. I would genuinely be interest in what you would have to say, since you seem to have a completely different opinion to that of Void.

Comment: The point is that you can send light of say 500 mm to something as small as an ion or molecule and that might be absorbed. I post an answer when I feel to / when possible. I am telling you are mixing different regimes I can't literally go to basis bcz ofmy ignorance. That would take me a lot of work I am not able to do here and now. Actually rereading your question it contains a lot of mix up concepts. The main point is that no matter how little the particles are, they can absorb light and reduce the light coming back to your eyes. Do not think of them as small pieces of gold, only.

Comment: Obviously I can have misunderstood the Question. This is possible.

Comment: @Garip shine light into a bunch of randomly arranged mirrors and very little of it will emerge out of them.

Comment: @Alchimista Interesting, that could explain why 30nm particles can absorb light at much higher wavelengths. I have been sceptical about that in Voids answer. But then how can I piece those things together? I know that part with the mirrors, but it works only for geometrical optics at wavelengths much smaller than the surface roughness. That is my example with the scratches on the plate seen in IR to be polished.

Comment: I could have taken this to much bottom-up. I mean when you mention np they can have kind of molecular absorption (they can be as small as a few dozen gold atoms!). Your question is probably more why a finely ground metal looks black,ie a sample which is not transparent. I think it simply mirroring in too much direction but I shall reread Void answer. It seems more or less correct, we are mixing much terms in this discussion. It is what I've signaled to him/her in my comment (that was a blocking screen it is not absorption, it is just blocking the light - nothing happens *within* the screen.

Comment: It should be useful even if it qualitative https://nanocomposix.com/pages/color-engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right intuition that light will interact with different structures based on their *scale*. Specifically, if a structure is much smaller than the light wavelength, the light will effectively smooth it out and ignore it. This is exactly the case of the scratches on the metal surface.

However, this will also happen for light passing around particles; if the particles are much smaller than its wavelength, it will ignore it or effectively interact with the "smoothed out" bulk. If, on the other hand, the size of the particle is comparable to the light's wavelength, it will interact, most likely absorbing the light. It turns out there are even [companies](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/materials-science/nanomaterials/gold-nanoparticles.html) that produce golden nanoparticles of various sizes to achieve different colors:

[image]

The point of these colors is that light of roughly the wavelength of the size of the particles gets absorbed, light of shorter wavelength gets diffused, and light of longer wavelengths sees the "smoothed out surface" and gets either neatly reflected or passes through.

Now to your example of black nanoparticles. The previous example corresponds to round nanoparticles, that is, particles that do not have any substructure. However, if you make a particle of a more complex shape involving more than one length-scale, such as the spike-balls below, they will absorb light of a broader range of wavelengths and thus a more "black-like" color.
[image]

From what I have read, a golden nanoparticle solution will degrade over time and the particles will get stuck together (aggregate). Various combinations of the aggregate particles provide various obstacles for light of various wavelengths and thus absorption of a broad spectrum. Broad-spectrum absorption (in the optical) is exactly what we call "being black".

Comment: Unfortunately obstacle and absorption isn't the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question boils down to: why do subwavelength indentations in a metal surface have little effect on the reflectance, wheras subwavelength metal particles can be highly absorptive?

As for the indentations: you need to distinguish between the depth and the width (or diameter) of the indentations. When the indentations are much more shallow than the wavelength [or more precisely, $\ll \lambda/(4\pi)$], they will not scatter much, never mind absorb much. For the diameter of the indentations, it works differently. It is very well possible that shallow indentations with steep side walls and subwavelength diameters affect the reflectance. Radiation (light) is essentially reflected from a metallic surface due to an oscillating electrical current that flows parallel to the surface and mostly parallel to the electric field of the radiation. Steep walls of indentations affect how this current can flow and will therefore also affect the reflectance.

For nanoparticles in suspension, such a current is not possible because the current cannot continue past the end of the particle. That's why small particles don't reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You‘re not missing anything, because the 2nd explanation about nanoparticles isn‘t really correct. It‘s a quantum effect whereas the first part is classical electrodynamics.

The phenomenon is called Localized Surface Plasmon Resonance (LSPR). It essentially results in absorption, in the case broad band probably due to a distribution of sizes. In void‘s picture the colors correspond to specific sizes.

In a nutshell: a plasmon is a charge (quasi) particle oscillation. In the case of light reflecting at an interface between a dielectric (e.g., like your liquid) & a metal,the SPR is excited in the metal and confined to the surface.

Gold nanoparticles suspended colloidally (like yours) are so small, that part of the surface fulfill the conditions for SPR regardless of the light direction. The size of the particle strongly influences the color.

The stained glass window in the Notre-Dame cathedral in Paris uses this effect for some colors.

If you‘re really interested check out this review paper: doi: 10.1088/1361-648X/aa60f3.